# Can't install php imap extension on centos 7

Tags: centos7, php-imap

Running command

> sudo yum install php56w-imap

gives me the output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: mirrors.163.com
 * updates: mirrors.163.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-imap.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: php56w-imap-5.6.22-1.w7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-imap-5.6.22-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           **Requires: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit)**
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm avoiding any compilation, so the --libdir=/usr/lib64 option for compiling php is not what I'm looking for. 
Also, I couldn't find any valid download link for this library. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

> https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc-client.so.2007()(64bit)

What I tried to install is libc-client-devel but it failed for dependency. with this  libc-client, everything works well

Answer (score 0):

just install first with command:

```
yum install php-imap*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an SE_UID not found error.

I just stumbled on https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/php72u-imap-7.2.17-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html

and then I ran:

```
yum install php72u-imap
```

I also created a php file with echo phpinfo() and saw that IMAP now shows up as a separate section in the display.